# How to handle different pilelinefactory?

Tags: netty

I'm a fresh man to the netty, there is one question trouble me days, here is the request:
I have tcp/ip frame to handle, and the data just like 53 46 10 FF 83 10 AF, and the 83 is the data type, can be 81/82/83, the different data type will have different pipeline to handle, so 81 may need send a message to echo, while 82 need not.
My idea is create different pipeline factory to create the related pipeline to handle different type message.

My question is: When the ServerBootstrap created it need set the pipeline factory, so I can just one pipeline factory, does anyone meet that request before?
Thanks so much to review and answer!

Answer (score 2):

Pipeline factory creates a pipeline for each connection. A pipeline is a list of handlers. You can't change the pipeline factory, but you can remove/add handlers in the created pipeline on the fly.

You can create a pipeline that has handler to detect data type (81/82/83). After detecting the data type, you can decide to add the suitable handler to handle next.